# Retrieve value of dropdownlist after saving to database on a button click

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am Working in an  MVC4 application where i need to save the dropdownlist value and retrive it from database.I have saved the value to the database but cant retrive back the value on click of a button.

**What i Want**:By Default My dropdownlist has values("Male","Female","Others").I am selecting  female and save it to the database.when i retrive from database it is loading with default values not showing selected value..

.CsHTML:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["GenderMaster"])
```

Model:

```
public string Gender   
    {
        set;
        get;
    }
```

Controller:

```
IEnumerable<BindindClass> gender = onjLoad.LoadGenderMaster();//Default dropdown binding
ViewData["GenderMaster"] = from c in gender
                           select new SelectListItem

                           {
                               Text = c.Text,
                               Value = c.Value,
                           };


item = onjLoad.ReadLoadPatientData(controlID["Gender"].ToString().Replace(",",""));
return View(item);

where item is the object of model,LoadGenderMaster() is the method used to get dropdown data from databse,ReadLoadPatientData() is the method which i use to retrive saved data from database.
```

Comment: Please provider more details and code samples. How does your view and controller look like.

Comment: Why do you want to retrieve the value when you already have it before saving it to the DB?

Comment: no the value i save it to the database..

Answer (score 0):

Please check and see if you have implemented the IsPostback property otherwise it will reset the value.